# Can't import shared python code from custom package

Tags: python

I'm new to python. Reading through the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), I'm prepared to put some shared code on a box. I inspected the path as such

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
```

In there I see */usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages*. Poking around in this directory there is a directory *yum*, and in there a file *yumRepo.py*. Back to the interpreter, I can run

```
>>> from yum import yumRepo
```

However, if I create a custom package/module like so (note all the other files are owned by root, thus the *sudo* here)

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/custom
sudo touch /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/custom/custom.py
```

and in *custom.py*

```
def testfunc():
    print('hello from custom module!')
```

I can't import it:

```
>>> from custom import custom
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named hnav
```

Permissions look pretty much the same as the *yum* package, other than that I have no **_*init*_.py** script, but would I really need one? How can I import code from this shared location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you do need an `__init__.py` file in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/custom to make it a Python package. This is documented here : http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/modules.html#packages

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the
>   directories as containing packages

Also, your own packages don't have to be in the system-wide `site-packages` directory, you can have them in any directory referenced in your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you, I must have glazed over that.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the `python setup.py` mechanism not always places the module/package where your current python installation will later on find them. For instance, if you happen to have the module/package source saved on `/usr/local/whatever`, and `/usr/local/lib/python/etc` is **not** an item of python's `sys.path`, `setup.py` might place the newly installed files on `/usr/local/lib/python/etc` anyway. You avoid this by specifying a `--prefix` option, like:

```
sudo python setup.py install --prefix /usr
```

Moreover, you have to **check the permissions** of the newly installed files and directories, especially if you used `sudo` commands. My import problem was simply solved by setting appropriate permissions to the newly installed module.